# Sticky footer with Twitter Bootstrap and Bonfire

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer, bonfire

I am using twitter bootstrap in Bonfire. I am trying to have a footer at the bottom page if there is less content, and if there is more content, the footer goes towards the end.

I have been trying for hours, and not able to find out what I am missing. I checked examples and codes available, but not able to find out what is different, or missing.

Would really appreciate if anyone could point out what is missed here.

```
    <!doctype html><head><meta charset="utf-8">


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/bonfire/public/themes/jumbotron/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/bonfire/public/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/bonfire/public/themes/jumbotron/css/footer_style.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/bonfire/public/themes/jumbotron/css/jumbotron.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/bonfire/public/themes/default/screen.css" media="screen" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/bonfire/public/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brokerage Free - PAN Services </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Apply for PAN <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ><a href="#">New PAN Application</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Replacement PAN Application</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Correction PAN Application</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li ><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Track Application Status</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>

          </ul>

    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>


<div class = "container">
<h1> Privacy Policy </h1>



We are a financial Services Company, offering a wide variety of Financial Services. 



</div><div class="push"></div>

<footer>
<div class="container">
<div class="span12">
    <div clas="row">
        <div class="span2 offset1"><a href="/bonfire/public/pan/about_us">About US</a></div>
        <div class="span2 "><a href="/bonfire/public/pan/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></div>
        <div class="span2 "><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></div>
        <div class="span2 "><a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
    </div>
<div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p align="center">&copy; Brokerage Free 2014. - All rights reserved.
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
</div>
```

The footer_style.css is given below:

```
<style>
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
footer {
color: #666;
background: #222;
padding: 17px 0 18px 0;
border-top: 1px solid #000;
height: 150px;
position: relative; 
}

footer a {
color: #999; 
}
footer a:hover {
color: #efefef;
text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -250px;
}
.push {
height: 63px;
}
/* not required for sticky footer; just pushes hero down a bit */
.wrapper > .container {
padding-top: 60px;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}


#main {
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom:250px; /* this needs to be bigger than footer height*/
}
.container .credit {
margin: 20px 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a CSS problem and had nothing to do with Bonfire. I am posting this solution so if someone has a similar problem in the future, might benefit out of this.

The following link helped me with finding a solution:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

The way to go about fixing this issue was to have a wrapper div, and a footer div that is outside of the wrapper div. The link has details.

Best.